# Record Create on the GoogleDoc object within Visual Workflow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I'm a low level SF admin who can assemble code 'recipes' but can't hard code things myself. I have the following use case:

Attach GoogleDoc to an Account object within the Flow functionality.

I would think that the solution would be as follows:

1. Create a Flow Plugin by making an Apex class implements the process.plugin interface
2. Create a new GoogleDoc record and pass 3 variables from the flow into the plugin

   - nameGD (variable created in my flow) to Name field on GoogleDoc object
   - workingdocAccountID (account ID) to ParentID field on GoogleDoc object
   - workingdocLink (doc url) to Url field on the GoogleDoc object

(Here's the link to the GoogleDoc object description - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_googledoc.htm)

This seems simple enough, but I don't know how to implement it. If someone could push me in the right direction with some code, I think I could run pretty far.

So, how do I get started?

Answer (score -1):

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Google_Data_API_Toolkit

above info will help you perhaps

Comment: Actually, I already have the data I need inside of the flow, so I won't need to call any API services. I need to push that data into the GoogleDoc object in salesforce (it's similar to the Attachments object).